# Communicate javascript and android service (Broadcast)?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

Is there any way to communicate or receive the android broadcast messages from JavaScript.
My Scenario is as follows.

My Colleagues already developed an android app which will raise a request to a back end connector and listens to its broadcast. On receiving  the response it parses and display it to user.

Now the new requirement turns out to be a mobile web. (i.e) I'm working on creating the front end in jquery mobile and have to communicate to the same or similar type of android service. I'm zero in android app development. Is there any way to do this?